# Give examples of extreme contractions over finite and infinite dimensional normed spaces with explanation.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I am studying about the extreme points of the unit ball of normed spaces. I am trying to see some explicit examples of extreme contractions so that it will be more easier to match the properties of an extreme contraction in either finite or infinite dimensional normed linear spaces. In search of some examples, I have met with an esteemed work done by **R. M. Blumenthal, J. Lindenstrauss and R. R. Phelps** titled as "EXTREME OPERATORS INTO $C(K)$". In this work they have mentioned a form of extreme contraction $Tf(k)=\lambda(k)(f\circ\psi)(k)$, where $T:C(K_1)\to C(K_2)$ is a bounded linear operator, $\lambda\in C(K_2)$ with $|\lambda|=1$, $\psi:K_2\to K_1$ is a continuous map and $k\in K_2$.

I am facing difficulty how to check $Tf$ is an extreme contraction. I have tried the definition "An element $T$ of $K$ is an extreme point of
K provided $T=\dfrac{T_1+T_2}{2}$ and $T_1, T_2\in K$ imply $T=T_1=T_2$" but cannot able to conclude. Any explanation regarding this will be very much helpful for me. Also, I am not getting how composition operators will become an extreme point of the unit ball $S(C(K_1), C(K_2))$ which is developed by **A. Ionescu Tulcea and C. Ionescu Tulcea** in their work "A NOTE ON EXTREME POINTS, dittoed notes" (not able to find the softcopy too).

In addition, I am eagerly expecting some other explicit examples of extreme contractions over any finite or infinite dimensional normed spaces or any references regarding these. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $$\tag1T=\frac12\,T_1+\frac12\,T_2$$ for contractions $T_1,T_2$.
Fix $k\in K_2$, and define linear functionals $\varphi,\eta_1,\eta_2\in C(K_1)^*$ by
$$\tag{$*$}
\varphi(f)=(Tf)(k),\qquad \eta_1(f)=(T_1f)(k),\qquad \eta_2(f)=(T_2f)(k). 
$$
Since $T,T_1,T_2$ are contractions, the three linear functionals have norm at most one. We have
$$
\varphi(f)=\lambda(k)\,f(\psi(k)),
$$
so $(1)$ becomes, with $\eta_j'=\lambda(k)^{-1}\,\eta_j$,
$$\tag2
f(\psi(k))=\frac12\,\eta_1'(f)+\frac12\,\eta_2'(f),\qquad\qquad f\in C(K_1). 
$$
This we can rewrite as
$$\tag3
\delta_{\psi(k)}=\frac12\,d\eta_1'+\frac12\,d\eta_2'. 
$$
Then [ones shows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4488345/22857) that $d\eta_1'=d\eta_2'=\delta_{\psi(k)}$. That is,
$$\tag4
(T_2f)(k)=(T_1f)(k)=\lambda(k)\,f(\psi(k)).
$$
As this can be done for any $k$ and any $f$, we have shown that $T_1=T_2=T$.

---

Some examples of extreme contractions:

- [Extreme points of state space of a C$^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401500/how-to-see-that-pure-states-are-multiplicative-linear-functionals-in-a-commutati/4401884#4401884).
- [Extreme points of the positive contractions in a C$^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2052062/22857).
- [Extreme points of the unital completely positive maps in a C$^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925204/extremality-of-automorphisms-of-c-algebras/1926146#1926146).
- [Extreme points of the unit ball of $C(X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483515/in-a-calgebra-the-set-of-extreme-points-of-barb-1-coincides-with-the-gr/4483773#4483773).
- [Extreme points among the selfadjoint contractions in a C$^*$-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232992/about-extreme-point-in-c-algebra/2233313#2233313).

Comment: Thank you for this explicit solution. It becomes really helpful for me. As a request, can you give some more examples of extreme contractions or any references where I can get such things?

Comment: I have edited a few links in.

Comment: Thank you so much